# How do I add a black hover to an image?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have small problem. I am beginner web developer. I make project in Bootstrap 4.

I have this code:

```
<section class="front-banners">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 pb-4 mb-md-1">
                    <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
                        <a href="/produkty"><img class="card-img front-banner-img" src="/img/banner.jpg" alt="Kuchnie"></a>
                        <a href="/produkty">
                            <div class="card-img-overlay front-banner-overlay">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Title </h5>
                                <img src="/img/arrow-front.png">
                                <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <p>Poznaj ofertę</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and my css:

```
.front-banner-overlay {
    background-color: rgb(255, 173, 51);
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.front-banner-overlay h5 {
    font-family: Inter;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #1A1A1A;
}

.front-banner-overlay p {
    font-family: Inter;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #1A1A1A;
}

.front-banner-overlay:hover {
    color: #1A1A1A;
}
```

I would like to add for:

```
<img class="card-img front-banner-img" src="/img/banner.jpg" alt="">
```

After hovering the cursor over the photos, I would like the photo to be black and white.

How can I do this?

Comment: add `filter: grayscale()` to image hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following css will work for you:

```
.card-img:hover{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```